# In QGIS is there a limit to subfolder nesting when save paths is relative?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

Setup is QGIS version is 3.28 on windows 11 with project property **Save Paths** set to relative.

I am following the instructions in the PyQGIS cookbook for adding layers using this code:

```
shp_filename= "C:/Users/anon/OneDrive/QPythonDev/pyqgis3_files/countries.shp"
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(shp_filename, "countries", "ogr")
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer
```

I can add a layer from the project folder or any other folder only when the full path is supplied. I cannot add with this (which is suggested in the [documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/loadlayer.html#vector-layers))

```
shp_filename = "data/countries.shp"
```

When the project is saved and reopened, the shapefile in the project folder loads - it is located in a sub-folder 5 folders in from the root:
C:/Users/anon/OneDrive/QPythonDev/pyqgis3_files/countries.shp

If I add a shapefile from a location such as C:\temp, that file is not found - this is the data source location given:
../../../../../../../temp/world.shp

If the project properties setting **Save Paths** is set to absolute, the files are found and loaded correctly.
My question is - is there a limit to folder nesting when you have **Save Paths** set to relative? And why does the relative file location "data/countries.shp" not work.